# Is there a Blender Python UI code to draw a horizontal line or vertical space?

Tags: python

So that in a tool shelve you can either via a line or a and empty space indicate groups of buttons without having to use the class command to define sections in a panel?

The only two ways I see currently is either via a label
[image]

Or via the class

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The definitive place for UI examples is the [UI cookbook](https://archive.blender.org/wiki/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface/). The layout templating syntax hasn't changed much since the early 2.5 releases.

There is `layout.separator()` for a subtle space between consecutive items. The vertical space is added automatically if multiple items appear on one row.

```
class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
        row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
        row.prop(scene, "frame_end")        
        layout.row().separator()
        row = layout.row()        
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
        row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
        row.prop(scene, "frame_end")                
        layout.row().separator()
        row = layout.row()        
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
        row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
```

[image]

Or for a more defined delineation, one might use `layout.box()`

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    scene = context.scene

    box = layout.box()
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")        

    box = layout.box()
    row = box.row()
    row.label('some label')
    row = box.row()        
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")                

    box = layout.box()
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
```

[image]

A vertical split using `box` and `column`. You might struggle with this, this is normal.

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    scene = context.scene

    col = layout.row()
    split = col.split(percentage=0.5)
    box = split.column().box()

    row = box.row()
    row.label('some label 1')
    row = box.row()        
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")        

    box = split.column().box()
    row = box.row()
    row.label('some label 2')
    row = box.row()        
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
    row = box.row()
    row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
    row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect - the box command perfectly can do this!

Comment: It seems like the link to the Cookbook is outdated, do you know where an updated one can be found?

Comment: @AnsonSavage the archived version of the link was not updated after 2.6 , but with few exceptions the content is still valid. Making a new cookbook for 3.x would certainly be nice now that there are quite a few "best practices" and new features.  But i will not be doing that.

Comment: Using `label` in 2.9 and majority of my UI becomes invisible.